# How to add data to a 2d array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi I have this code in python 3.8:

```
import numpy as np
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
xyz = [x,y,z]
np_xyz= np.array([])
np_xyz = np.append(np_xyz,xyz)
print(np_xyz)
ptint("-----")
x = 4
y = 5
z = 6
xyz = [x,y,z]
np_xyz = np.append(np_xyz,xyz)
print(np_xyz)
```

It output:

```
[1 2 3]
-----
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

I want it to output something like:

```
[[1 2 3]]
-----
[[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]]
```

can someone please help me I'm completely lost with numpy I tried a lot of thing from google but I found no solution to my problem. Thanks

Comment: Your question title says that you want a 3D array, but the expected output in your question shows a 2D array?

Comment: Did your 'googling' include reading the docs for `np.apppend`?  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html.  `np.append` is a poorly name 'front-end' to `np.concatenate`.  People tend to think it will behave just like a list append.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reshape the array. The following outputs an array with dimensions 2 x 3.

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
arr.reshape((2,3))
```

Output: array([[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6]])

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.vstack()` to stack arrays vertically:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b =  np.array([4, 5, 6])
np.vstack([a, b])
```

it gives:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```